# How to pass argument of hex string in the form of "\x" in vscode, launch.json

Tags: c, json, visual-studio-code, parameter-passing

I noticed that in vscode, if I specify `"\\xD0\\x00"` in launch.json like so, the backslash gets removed, and the argument ends up becoming like `"xD0x00"`.

If the argument is in the form of `"\xD0\x00"`, it ends up becoming like `"D000"`.

How do I pass the argument so that it gets picked up as `"\xD0\x00"`?

```
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "gcc.exe - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [
                "-p",
                "\\xD0\\x00"                
            ],
```

Comment: I tried with Powershell and using `"\\xD0\\x00"` in the launch config gets quoted and passed like `'\xD0\x00'`

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following ways, which may help you.

`\/xD0\/x00`

Comment: it becomes "/xD0/x00"

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using passing '"\\xD0\\x00"' as argument in launch.json.

This argument gets passed as "\xD0\x00", with an extra function to looking for the double "\" instead of a single "".